# getting extra zero's while printing vector data?

Tags: c++, vector

What is wrong with this code? I am not getting correct data. when I printed out the data in vector I am getting extra 0's at the beginning equal to the number of elements to be inserted.

```
int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */  

    int rows,query;
    // scanf("%d %d",&rows,&query);
    cin>>rows>>query;
    vector < vector <int> > arr(rows);
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        int size;
        // scanf("%d",&size);
        cin>>size;
        // arr[i].resize(size);
        arr[i]=vector <int>(size);
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
            int data;
            // scanf("%d",&data);
            cin>>data;
            arr[i].push_back(data);
        }

    }



     for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
         for(int j=0;j<arr[i].size();j++){
             cout<<arr[i][j];
         }
         cout<<"\n";
     }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide example input, actual output and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating vectors that already contain `size` elements:

```
arr[i] = vector<int>(size);
```

and then later on you just append more elements:

```
arr[i].push_back(data);
```

As a result, each vector has `size * 2` elements. Simply delete the `arr[i] = vector<int>(size);` line. The `push_back()` operation is enough. It automatically resizes the vector to fit the newly added elements.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! The issue is resolved.

Comment: Alternatively, stick with the `[]` notation and change the `push_back` line to `arr[i][j] = data;`. Less STLish and more Cish, but works fine. Either way, stick to one method of assignment - `push_back(x)` or `[i] = x`.